# restore last deleted directory

Tags: linux

I have deleted a directory mistakenly on linux. Is it possible to recover it. My File system is ext3. Please advice

Answer (score 1):

http://studyhat.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-recover-deleted-files-in-fedora.html

above link may help you recover deleted directory :)